# postgres_fdw: possible to push data to foreign server for join?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgres-fdw

suppose I have a query like

```
select * from remote_table
   join local_table using(common_key)
```

where remote_table is a `FOREIGN TABLE` with `postgres_fdw` and `local_table` is a regular table.

`local_table` is small (100 rows) and `remote_table` is large (millions of rows).

It looks like the remote table is pulled in its entirety and joined locally, when it would be more efficient to ship the smaller table to the remote server and join remotely.

Is there a way to get postgres_fdw to do that?

Comment: A CTE might allow the push-down? I didn't test: `WITH cte AS (SELECT common_key FROM local_table)
SELECT * FROM remote_table
WHERE common_key IN (TABLE cte);` On second though: I doubt that can fly ...

Comment: There was a related question for another FDW, and I came up with an idea that did not work. Might work for postgres_fdw (and Postgres 12?) though. You might want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493138/939860

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with a join, since joins between tables on different servers are always executed locally.

What you could try is something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM remote_table
      WHERE common_key IN (SELECT common_key FROM local_table)
     ) a
  JOIN local_table USING (common_key);
```

I did not test it, so I am not sure if it will work, but the idea is to use a condition for the foreign table scan that can be pushed down and reduces the amount of data fetched as much as possible.

Comment: No, this will have the same issue as a join.  WHERE clauses will only be pushed down if they can be executed remotely.  The only way this would work is if you pushed the contents of `local_table` itself to the remote DB.

Comment: Well, think of a different solution along the lines of my answer, e.g. constructing an `IN` list from the result of `SELECT common_key FROM local_table`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deploying the local data into a temp table on the foreign server then joining it into the foreign table? Not sure of your process or if this would be efficient for you or not.