# How can I select all rows from different tables when the query returns multiple min(count) data

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

Consider I have the below tables created and the relationships are created as per the ER Diagram.
[image: ER Diagram]

I have been asked to find which project(s) have the least number of employees. I tried to use the below code, but I am getting only 1 output, whereas I am expecting two records to be created as per the data fed:

`select pname from project p where pnumber = (select min(count) from (select count(*) from works_on group by pno)t)`

Below are the data in the table:

Employee table:
[image]

Project Table:

[image]

Works_On Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In **Postgres 13** (currently RC), this becomes dead simple using the new [**`WITH TIES`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT):

```sql
SELECT pno
FROM   works_on
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY count(*)
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;  -- new & hot
```

If you need more project attributes, join to table `project` *after* identifying the "winning" project numbers cheaply form `works_on` alone. That's fastest.

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM  (
   SELECT pno AS pnumber
   FROM   works_on
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY count(*)
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
   ) w
JOIN  project p USING (pnumber);
```

Related:

- [Get apps with the highest review count since a dynamic series of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310905/get-apps-with-the-highest-review-count-since-a-dynamic-series-of-days/63320975#63320975)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend aggregation and window functions.

The logic is to count the number of employees per project, then use window functions to rank the projects. `ran()` comes handy, because it allows ties:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*, count(*) cnt_employees, rank() over(order by count(*)) rn
    from project p
    inner join works_on wo on wo.pno = p.pnumber
    group by p.pno
) t
where rn = 1
```